# .net scale down images in server upon upload if past size limit

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-resizing, imageresizer

When user uploads file,

What is the best way to check if the image width / height is over a set limit, and resize the image if needed?

Currently I am experimenting with saving the `HttpPostedFileBase` to a temp folder in order to load it using `Bitmap.FromFile()` just ti check the width/height of the image.

Then, use `ImageResizer` library to resize the image using `ImageResizer.ImageJob`.

So far I am hitting `out of memory exception` at the  `Bitmap.FromFile(path)` stage.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075906/using-c-sharp-how-can-i-resize-a-jpeg-image

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer 3.4 includes a new ImageUploadHelper project/plugin to make this safer and easier. (You can find this in the /Plugins folder of the [source download](http://imageresizing.net/download), but it doesn't yet have a NuGet package as it's still in preview.

```
long pixels = 0;

try{
  var size = ImageUploadHelper.GetImageSize(httpPostedFile);
  pixels = size[0] * size[1];
} catch{} //Corrupted images will cause an OutOfMemoryException.

string resultPath = null;
if (pixels > 3 * 1000 * 1000){
  var j = new ImageJob(httpPostedFile,"~/uploads/<guid>.<ext>", new Instructions("maxwidth=1700&maxheight=1700");
  j.Build();
  resultPath = PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath(j.FinalPath);
}else{
  resultPath = "~/uploads/" + ImageUploadHelper.SaveUploadedFileSafely("~/uploads",httpPostedFile);
}
```