# Winform auto size to picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm wanting my winform to conform to the size of an image I pass to an image box held on my form. When I start the program it looks like this:
[image]

Then when I pass an image to my picture box it reshapes to this:
[image]

However, what I actually want is for the winform to resemble this. I had to manually drag the window to get it this way:
[image]

I'm not entirely sure how I can achieve the third one via code. At the moment this is what i have:

```
this.Size = new Size(imagePreview.Width, imagePreview.Height);
```

Is there something else I can do code wise so i always end up with the result in the third picture, no matter what size of the image?

Comment: Pretty sure there is a Minimum size property

Comment: this.ClientSize = new Size(imagePreview.Right, imagePreview.Bottom);

Comment: Hans - worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one built-in property that could help you - Size Mode. Try it and if this does not suit your needs you can implement your own method for  [this - click me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075906/using-c-sharp-how-can-i-resize-a-jpeg-image)